# Mule 4 : How to validate a payload input against an entry in xml file under resources folder?

Tags: mule, mulesoft

Basically I need to validate a payload value xyz , if this exist is in the xml under the this tag xyz

Comment: Please add examples of the input to validate and the XML resource so we can understand the structures. Also show an example of the validation failing and one of being valid for context.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test if there is an element with some name under the top element of the reference XML you can read it first with `<parse-template>`, put the information into a variable and use it to index by element name.

Example:

src/main/resource/data.xml:

```
<root>
    <abc>element 1</abc>
    <xyz>element 2</xyz>
</root>
```

Test flow:

```
<flow name="validateFlow">
    <http:listener doc:name="Listener" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/"/>
    <set-payload value="xyzx" />
    <parse-template location="data.xml" target="data" outputMimeType="application/xml"/>
    <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message">
        <ee:message >
            <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
                output application/java
                --- 
                if (vars.data.payload.root[payload]?) "present" else "not present"
            ]]></ee:set-payload>
        </ee:message>
    </ee:transform>     
</flow>
```

If you want to make a validation you might want to see the [Validation Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/validation-connector/1.4/) with a similar expression than in the example.